# $_GET reads url as string and not as an array

Tags: php

My $_GET is reading the URL as a string and does not separate different GET variables.

My URL is:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?cat=archive?page=2
```

Using $_GET I'd like to use the variables $cat and $page.

```
echo $_GET['cat'];
```

Returns: archive?page=2.

```
echo $_GET['page'];
```

Returns: nothing.

What am I doing wrong here? Should I manually separate the URL into variables?

Comment: that `?` (*between `archive` and `page`*) should be `&` otherwise it reads it as a string, as you can see in your code.

Answer (score 0):

the '?' is only used once in the url.  you should use & to separate each variable.

your URL should be  www.mysite.com/index.php?cat=archive&page=2

and then you can echo on cat and page

Answer (score 0):

url in not correct form where you are made it

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?cat=archive?page=2
```

correct it with

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?cat=archive&page=2
```